# How can i write a code or that displays the most rented book type in my programming code of a library system?

Tags: java

I think i wrote a code wrong in my programming code because the outcome displays a number for the most rented book type instead of the name of the book type. For example a person borrows a Novel book type and another person borrows a Novel book type as well. So when i run the program, it displays a data list and contains 2 people borrowing the same book type which is Novel and later it display "The most rented book type is: 2". When it should display "The most rented book type is: Novel"

Here is my programming Java code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class BookRentalShop 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of data you want to see: ");
        int inputnum = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        String[] Name = new String[inputnum];
        String[] Bookname = new String[inputnum];
        String[] AuthorName = new String[inputnum];
        String[] Booktype = new String[inputnum];
        int[] NumbersofDaysBorrowed = new int[inputnum];
        int[] RentalCharges = new int[inputnum];
        String[] Types = {"Cartoon","Magazine", "Short story", "Long story", "Journal", "Novel", "Encyclopedia"};
        int[] count = new int[7];

    for (int d = 0; d < inputnum; d = d + 1) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the person:");
        Name[d] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the bookname:");
        Bookname[d] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the author's name:");
        AuthorName[d] = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the book type:");
        Booktype[d] = sc.nextLine();
        for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++)
        {
            if (Booktype[d].equals(Types[k]))
            {
                count[k]++; 
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Enter the number of days that the book had been borrowed:");
        NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Cartoon")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 500;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Magazine")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 1000;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Short story")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 500;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Long story")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 1500;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Journal")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 350;
        } else if (Booktype[d].equalsIgnoreCase("Novel")) 
        {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 1500;
        } else {
            RentalCharges[d] = NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] * 2500;
        }
  if(NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] > 5)
        {
            int bookCost = RentalCharges[d] / NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d];
            RentalCharges[d] = (5 * bookCost) + ((NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d] - 5) * (bookCost / 2)); 
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("%s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20s\n", "No", "Name", "Bookname", "AuthorName", "Booktype", "Numbers of Days Borrowed", "Rental Charges");
    for (int d = 0; d < inputnum; d = d + 1) 
    {
        int num = d + 1;
        System.out.printf("%s %20s %20s %20s %20s %20d %20d\n", num, Name[d], Bookname[d], AuthorName[d], Booktype[d], NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d], RentalCharges[d]);
    }
    String again = "Yes";
    String exist = "No";
    while (again.equals("Yes")) {
        exist = "No";
        System.out.println("enter the search name");
        String searchname = sc.nextLine();
        for (int d = 0; d < inputnum; d = d + 1) {
            if (searchname.equals(Name[d])) {
                System.out.println("Name           : " + Name[d]);
                System.out.println("Bookname       : " + Bookname[d]);
                System.out.println("Number of Days Borrowed : " + NumbersofDaysBorrowed[d]);
                exist = "Yes";
            }
        }
        if (exist.equals("No")) {
            System.out.println("The search name requested is not found");
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to search again? (Yes,No) ");
        again = sc.nextLine();
    }
    *int max = count[0];
    for (int d = 0; d < 7; d = d + 1)
    {
        for (int k =  d + 1; k < 7; k = k + 1)
        {
            if (count[k] > count[d]) 
            {
                max = count[k];
            }
            else {
                max = count[d];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The most rented booktype is: " + max);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

}*

Here is the outcome of the code:

```
No                 Name             Bookname           AuthorName             Booktype Numbers of Days Borrowed       Rental Charges
1                    J                Grere              bvcnvnb              Journal                    3                 1050
2                    K               wqerwr               xczzzx                Novel                    6                 8250
3               opoipo            kkghjhjgh             bvcbcvbc              Cartoon                    5                 2500
4                    Q              erwytiu             ghfghgfd             Magazine                    7                 6000
5                    D         sdsafhgjhgjk         vvbbnbn,nbvc                Novel                    6                 8250
enter the search name
No
The search name requested is not found
Do you want to search again? (Yes,No) 
No

The most rented booktype is: 2
```

I indicated where i think the code is wrong with a star (*) which is near the end of my code.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing out the `int` value and not the String. Try printing out `Booktype[max]`

```
System.out.println("The most rented booktype is: " + Booktype[max]);
```